# Does Factory Reset reset Xposed Modifications, especially on Note 3 SM-N900 Exynos?

Tags: rooting, factory-reset, odin, samsung-galaxy-note-3, xposed-framework

or I need other steps to **RESTORE Xposed** and everything back to like I first receive it **without** the need to Flash with Odin. Because I either hard or softbricked my device using it! I am scared of it now. I rooted using Kingo Android ROOT for further info.. :) I want to reset because my device kinda laggy and I can not disable some Device Admin.. So, it is kinda messed up.. I want to start over with **no Odin** at all?

Comment: My device it OK, I just want to restore things up. No, I didnt create backup ROM with CWM. Yes, CWM is there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xposed will survive, and your root should as well. But you'll need to reinstall the Xposed installer app and any xposed modules you had installed before you factory reset.

EDIT: So, to clarify, xposed modifies /system/bin/app_process to "hook" in to android. This modification is not touched by a factory reset. Nor is the `su` binary. However, the Xposed installer app (which is responsible for the upgrading of the app_process modifications), and any xposed modules will be cleared.

Comment: I'm not sure about the wording here: Xposed will survive, but you'll need to reinstall. So in a sense it doesn't really survive. It can be used, but must be reinstalled. Most, if not all of the modules can be backed up with Titanium Backup or others, and set to how they were, after reinstallation to be 100% sure. You're not wrong, I'm just not sure that it really 'survives' it just doesn't horribly die!

Comment: Yep, I agree with RossC. I think what happen here is that the XPOSED framework is installed inside the SYSTEM. THEREFORE THE FRAMEWORK IS NOT UNINSTALLED HOWEVER THE USER INSTALLED APPS IS REMOVED LIKE THE MODULES AND THE XPOSED ITSELF.